# Did Lovegood's attempted (and inaccurate) replica of Ravenclaw's diadem actually work and thus give Harry special wisdom?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

In  "Harry Potter And The Deathly Hallows" Harry, Ron and Hermione are visiting Xenophilius Lovegood, because they wanted to know more about the Mark of the (for them at this poit still unknown) Deathly Hallows. Xenophilius let them in and led them up the stairs. 
After a little conversation with him, Xenophilius went down allegedly to inform Luna, that her friends where there. While his absence, Harry recognized this object. When Xenophilius returns with tea:

*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 20: Xenophilius Lovegood Page 329*

> "Ah, you have spotted my pet invention," [Xenophilius] said (...)
>   He indicated the objects like ears-trumpets.
>   "These are the Wrackspurt siphons - to remove all sources of distraction from the thinker's immediate area. Here," he pointed out the tiny wings, "a Billywig propeller, to induce an elevated frame of mind. Finally," he pointed to the orange radish, "a Dirigible Plum, so as to enhance the ability to accept the extraordinary."

Then, the description of Xenophilius's "pet invention"

Now one reason I got suspicious was because the headdress on Rowena Ravenclaw's head was described in such detail. Another reference that could be a hint was that the bust landed near Harry after the explosion.

*Chapter 22: The Tale of the three brothers Page 342*

> "There was a colossal explosion. (...)
>       Half buried in rubble, Harry tried to raise himself (...) [The bust of Rowena Ravenclaw lay beside him with half of its face missing] (...) "

Then they disapparated and had a conversation whether to believe what Xenophilius told them about the Deathly Hallows or not. Hermione doesn't, but Harry gets more and more suspicious.

*Chapter 23: The Deathly Hallows Page 347*

> "(Hermione says) "If surviving was as simple as hiding under the Invisibility Cloak, we'd haye everything we need already!"
>       "I don't know. We could do with an unbeatable wand," said Harry (...)
>       "There's no such thing, Harry!""

Basically after that Harry tries to convince Hermione that it isn't that unbelievable as she had suspected it. Then Harry remembers the Gaunt family:

*Page 348*

> "Marvolo Gaunt! You-Know-Who's grandfather! In the Pensieve! With Dumbledore! Marvolo Gaun said he was descended from the Peverells."
>       (...) "The ring, the ring that became a Horcrux, Marvolo Gaunt said the Peverell coat of arms on it! (...)
>       "The Peverell coat of arms?" said Hermione sharply. "Could you see what it looked like?"
>       ["Not really," said Harry, trying to remember.]"

So Harry said he could not see it but then he gets more excited and remembers more and more about the Peverells,  the information he heard so far about his Invisibility Cloak and the Stone he just had seen once in his life from close up and also "abandoning caution"

*Page 349*

> "Well, why not? Why not?" said Harry, abandoning  caution. (...) Hermione, it fits of its own accord! [I know the sign of the Deathly Hallows was on that stone!] Gaunt said he was descended from the Peverells!"
>       "A minute ago you told us you never saw the mark on the stone properly!" (...)

Then it also says:

> [But Harry's imagination was racing ahead, far beyond Ron and Hermione's...] (...)
>       "Ignotus Peverell is buried in Godric's Hollow... (...) He's my ancestor! I'm descended from the third brother! It all makes sense!"(...) "

After that Harry puts everything together that he can think of. When he wanted to give the Letter to Hermione that Lily had once written to Sirius the Snitch falls out of his pouch:

*Page 351*

> "Something fell to the floor and rolled, glittering, under a chair: he had dislodged the Snitch (...)
>       "IT'S IN HERE! He (Dumbledore) left me the ring - it's in the Snitch!" (...) It was so obvious, so clear to Harry: everything fitted, everything ... (...)
>       "You-Know-Who's after the Elder Wand." (...) He knew it was the truth. It all made sense"

Then again what made me even more suspicious:

*Page 352*

> ["He felt light-headed with amazement at his discoveries. (...) Didn't they (Ron and Hermione) realise how far they had travelled in the last few minutes?]
>       "This is it," Harry said, trying to bring them inside the glow of his own astonished certainty. "This explains everything. The Deathly Hallows are real, and I've got one -  maybe two- (...) But don't you see? It all fits-"

Now could it be, that Harry just had this flash of realisation because this headdressing was near his head? Or was it even possibly the "tea" they were drinking from Xenophilius. I was wondering that mainly because Harry was the one who was so excited about the thoughts he had and Ron and Hermione weren't.

Does someone know if JKR was ever been asked that and if so did she answer this question?

Comment: I *think* I understand what you are asking: did Lovegood's attempted (and inaccurate) replica of Ravenclaw's diadem actually work and thus give Harry special wisdom? The question needs a lot of clean-up though. If that is what you are asking, I think it's patently silly, but clever

Comment: For your quotes, could you use `>` at the beginning of each line instead of ticks?

Comment: @NKCampbell Yes. Thank you.

Comment: I've downvoted. You already know everything there is to know about this minor plot contrivance and there's nothing in any source to indicate it was anything other than a replica.

Comment: His stroke of inspiration was a result of a lesser-known illness named Movingtheplotonitis.

Comment: @Valorum, Richard, *OP* asks about *interviews*, which OP "already **doesn't** know". Were OP right it would be the tipping point for Harry.

Comment: @n611x007 - As with all of these "idle speculation" questions, there's no harm in closing them and re-opening them if an answer (as unlikely as it seems) happens along. Otherwise the site would be entirely inundated with an infinite number of daft fan-theory questions.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the most recent info about the Wizarding World, the answer is a firm *maybe*.

The three elements of his 'diadem' are;

- **Billywig wings**, which seem pretty useless. Their [sting](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Billywig_sting) is known to have psychoactive properties (causing euphoria and literally light-headedness) but their wings appear to be simply used to keep the insect aloft.
- **Wrackspurt siphons**, which, at first glance (e.g. based on the HP canon books) seemed totally pointless, may actually have some positive benefits to clear-headedness now that wrackspurts have been established by *Harry Potter: Wizards Unite* as actually [existing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_X2szXUxlk). One assumes that having them in your brain isn't likely to have a *positive* effect.
- **Dirigible plums**, which are now known, courtesy of *Harry Potter: Hogwarts Mystery*, to not only float magically but also have [a medicinal property when eaten](https://youtu.be/ussGWU2FldU?t=884). Being in their presence isn't known to have any effect whatsoever, however.

---

It's not clear if they have any of the above have the ability to impact on thinking (and certainly not in a positive way) by mere *proximity*, but it at least now seems possible, however unlikely, that this magical diadem replacement has some efficacy, especially if Harry inadvertently ingested some of the parts.

Comment: Respect for tackling the question but I'm really not sure how much credence I give mobile games. Fantastic Beasts (the book) and Pottermore are written by JK Rowling whereas these games are, as I understand it, just using the license Warner Bros has to do their own thing. Since there's no formal Harry Potter canon it's technically legit, I suppose. Just not for book purists like me.